# Get Font Properties From Word Document With OpenXML (.NET)

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

**How can I get font properties from word document with OpenXML?**

```
var para = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList();
```

With the code above, I can only get the paragraphs themselves.

Only font insertion shown in forum.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Although i don't really know, what 'font-properties' means in this context, my answer is: it depends.

- styles (templates defining paragraph or run format, etc) are set in `MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart`
- formatting properties are defined in `RunProperties` or `ParagraphProperties` (applied styles can also be found here)

So if you like to retrieve certain formatting properties, you will have to look inside the openxml-package.